# Images Maps SEO and Accessibility

Tags: html, images, accessibility

My question of the day is about image maps and accessibility.

Now it is my understanding that whenever you use an alt tag within an img  tag you describe the image which increases the user experience for those who are blind or just people whom have just disabled images from rendering for one reason or many.

Now this logic doesn't seem to work with Image Maps which I'll demonstrate an example.

```
<img alt="Image Map of Bits and Bobs" usemap="#imgmap" src="bits-and-bobs">
  <map name="imgmap">
    <area shape="poly" coords="" href="" alt="Spanner" title="Guitars Repairs"/>
    <area shape="poly" coords="" href="" alt="Dollar" title="Guitars for Sale"/>
    <area shape="poly" coords="" href="" alt="eLearning" title="Learning about Guitars"/>
    <area shape="poly" coords="" href="" alt="String" title="How to tune a Guitar"/>
  </map>
```

***Valid Href's and Coords removed for easier viewing***...

So as you can see in the above image I'm describing the area of the image rather that the outcome if they click the image. So my question is simple....

Within a image map that contains links do you describe the link outcome rather describe the image... For example a image of strings using strings wouldn't indicate that its a link about how to tune a guitar, however the title tag does.

Comment: PS. I've never had to use image maps before, personally I dislike em but I've been requested and with blind users in mind.

Answer (score 6):

In general, if a link only contains an image, [the `alt` attribute of that image should *not* describe the image but the link target](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/48817/17023).

With image maps, it’s the same.

The `alt` attribute of the `img` element should describe the whole image (as the image itself is not linked).

The `alt` attribute of the `area` element should describe its purpose (as this image area is linked, so the link is important, not the image).

Reference: [HTML5 (CR from 2013-08-06): `area` → `alt`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/embedded-content-0.html#attr-area-alt):

> It [*the `alt` attribute*] specifies the text of the hyperlink. Its value must be text that, when presented with the texts specified for the other hyperlinks of the image map, and with the alternative text of the image, but without the image itself, provides the user with the same kind of choice as the hyperlink would when used without its text but with its shape applied to the image.

FWIW, [WCAG’s technique H37](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20130905/H37.html) (informational, not normative) has an example for the `img`-`alt` that includes also an instruction to select an area:

> An image on a Web site depicts the floor plan of a building. The image is an image map with each room an interactive map area. The alt text is "The building's floor plan. Select a room for more information about the purpose or content of the room." The instruction to "select a room" indicates that the image is interactive.

Personally, I’m not so sure about this. I think if such an instruction would be needed, it should be part of the prosa text near the image map.

---

So in your example, you should use the content of the `title` attributes as `alt` content (and probably remove the `title` attributes as to not repeat this content).

As I didn’t see your image, I can only guess here, but I assume the image consists of 4 icons without any textual label. If so, the [guideline for icon image](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/embedded-content-0.html#icon-images) might apply here:

> An icon is usually a simple picture representing a program, action, data file or a concept.

In which case the `img`-`alt` shouldn’t describe the (beauty of the) icons but what they *represent*.

If my assumption is correct, this doesn’t seem to be a perfect candidate for an image map, but, oh well, *clients*.